# iOS Error: Unable to locate resource <PHInternalAssetResource: 0x1700f5580>

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uikit, phassetslibrary

I'm playing with Photo library on iOS device. I try to write `PHAssetResource` to a local file. Sometimes it works sometimes it doesn't and I get an error `Error: Unable to locate resource <PHInternalAssetResource: 0x1740e8900> type=photo size={3264, 2448} fileSize=3185088 uti=public.jpeg filename=IMG_6683.JPG assetLocalIdentifier=BF00A76D-AC8E-4481-BC45-3E18D80C656D/L0/001`. 
It happens for `PHAssets` that are not on local device. I set `isNetworkAccessAllowed` of `PHAssetResourceRequestOptions` to true and check progress and it reports that downloading stop on 0,5 and thorw above error.

I wonder what happened. I can't find any explanation in docs.

Comment: I'm on the same boat here. Did you ever find out what is happening with this? I figured out that if you simply call the same method again then it actually works :/

Comment: What's going on? My code worked fine since iOS 9.1 but it's now broken with iOS 10.3.. maybe 10.2

Comment: I reliably get this error when progress reaches 50%. iOS 10.2.1. Retrying the request works fine (and is faster). I've filed a radar for this: http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=5053868303974400